# Use python + Selenium + Beautiful Soup to find URL with fixed string

Tags: python, selenium, url, beautifulsoup, webdriver

I have some URLs as below:

```
imsges = 
<img class="wni-logo" src="https://smtgvs.weathernews.jp/s/topics/img/wnilogo_kana@2x.png"/>
<img alt="top" id="top_img" src="//smtgvs.weathernews.jp/s/topics/img/201808/201808170115_top_img_A.jpg?1534474260" style="width: 100%;"/>
<img alt="box0" id="box_img0" src="//smtgvs.weathernews.jp/s/topics/img/201808/201808170115_box_img0_A.png?1534474573" style="width:100%"/>
<img alt="box1" class="lazy" data-original="https://smtgvs.weathernews.jp" id="box_img1" src="https://smtgvs.weathernews.jp/s/topics/img/dummy.png" style="width: 100%; display: none;"/>
<img alt="recommend thumb0" height="70" src="https://smtgvs.weathernews.jp/s/topics/thumb/article/201808080245_top_img_A_320x240.jpg?1534473603" width="100px"/>
```

and I want to get results as below:

```
['https://smtgvs.weathernews.jp/s/topics/img/201808/201808170115_top_img_A.jpg']
['https://smtgvs.weathernews.jp/s/topics/img/201808/201808170115_box_img0_A.png']
```

I tried this code:

```
for image in images:
    imageURL = re.findall('https://smtgvs.weathernews.jp/s/topics/img/.+', urljoin(baseURL, image['src']))

    if imageURL:
        print(imageURL)
```

I got those results, can you correct it for me?

```
['https://smtgvs.weathernews.jp/s/topics/img/201808/201808170115_top_img_A.jpg?1534474260']
['https://smtgvs.weathernews.jp/s/topics/img/201808/201808170115_box_img0_A.jpg?1534474573']
['https://smtgvs.weathernews.jp/s/topics/img/dummy.png']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly change your regex with a capturing group

```
for image in images:
     imageURL = re.findall("(https://smtgvs.weathernews.jp/s/topics/img/[0-9]+/.+)\?[0-9]+", urljoin(baseURL, image['src']))

if imageURL:
    print(imageURL)
```

Edit: to get data-original instead of src field:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
for image in soup.find_all("img"):
    print(image.get("data-original"))
```

Comment: How can I get URL in `data-original` not in `src`? `<img alt="box3" class="lazy" data-original="https://smtgvs.weathernews.jp/s/topics/img/201807/201807260215_box_img3_A.jpg?1532595230" id="box_img3" src="https://smtgvs.weathernews.jp/s/topics/img/dummy.png" style="width:100%"/>`

Comment: @mikezang I answer with an edit in my answer :)  : `image.get("data-original")`